MobileRTC version incompatible on join
We have facing issue in join zoom meeting using zoom sdk in react native.
It reads “the mobilertc version is incompatible”. Previously this was working.
Same thing working proper in android app but faced issue in iOS only.
We are using react native zoom us sdk.
"react-native-zoom-us": "6.18.0" SDK.
Using below react native version :-
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.72.12
node version :-
v21.7.1
Xcode :- 15.1
iOS :- 17.4.1
Thank you
